# Parsing dictionary from plist into array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

could anyone help with loading dictionary objects correctly into the array.
Loading of plist into dictionary object works fine, and I was able to output some of it into command-line. 
Problem is that this way of loading bundles each Name and Price sets into same cell in the array.
IE: 
 Is it possible to load them separately? Or perhaps in some sort of 2d array with one cell for name and other for price.

Thanks in advance.

Test is a mutable array.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"property" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* amountData =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (amountData) {
    Test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: amountData];
}
```

And my plist structure is:

```
<dict>
<key>New item</key>
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Property 1</string>
    <key>Price</key>
    <string>100000</string>
</dict>
<key>New item - 2</key>
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Property 2</string>
    <key>Price</key>
    <string>300000</string>
</dict>
<key>New item - 3</key>
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Property 3</string>
    <key>Price</key>
    <string>500000</string>
</dict>
<key>New item - 4</key>
<dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Property 4</string>
    <key>Price</key>
    <string>600000</string>
</dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you directly store it as an array? Your file would look like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>...</dict>
    <dict>...</dict>
    <dict>...</dict>
</array>
```

And you could do something like this:

```
NSArray *amountData =  [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Otherwise the right way to do it would be this:

```
Test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [amountData allValues]];
```

Comment: Problem with array method is that it returns each row as:
Row 0: {
    Name = "Property 1";
    Price = 100000;
}

I was wondering if theres easier way of loading this, without having to manually parse brackets etc.
Or if I could access value directly from Dictionary to pull out lets say Name.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your problem. What you'll get is the array you wanted. Getting all names could be done using somethink like this: `[Test valueForKeyPath: @"name"]` -- returns you an Array with all names.

Comment: This sounds like what I was looking for ;D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the call

```
Test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: amountData];
```

when amountData is an NSDictionary, not an array… As Max has suggested, you can just store an array plist instead of a dictionary plist.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"property" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* amountData =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (amountData) {
    Test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [amountData allValues]];
}
```